# Prolog - query outputs limited answers

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

To begin with - this is coursework so I can't post code. This is more about how prolog outputs its answers rather than "is my code right"?

I'm creating a predicate that returns all simple paths between a graph, given a list of edges.

For example, `paths(a, X)` will return all the possible paths that start with `a`.

Say my KB is:
    edge(a,b).
    edge(b,c).
    edge(c,d).
    edge(d,f).

Then I should get `X = [[a], [a,b], [a,b,c], [a,b,c,d], [a,b,c,d,f]]` - and I do. The problem is, if the output is longer, then it doesn't show every possible output - the output is shown as follows:

```
Paths = [[b],[b,c],[b,c,d],[b,c,d,a],[b,c,d,e],[b,c,d,f],[b,c,d,f|...]] ?
```

y

Is there any way I can make my interpreter explicitly show everything? The last list is incomplete - it should show [b,c,d,f,g]. For the record, I'm using SICSTUS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a printing habit of prolog when lists get long, it only prints some prefix. try adding a `print(Paths)` goal. That should show you the actual, non-truncated, list.

Comment: @user2832891: This gives unexpected values for terms that need quoting. And does not take variable names into account...

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing answers printed by the toplevel that have been abbreviated. In SICStus, the precise way of printing at the toplevel is determined by the Prolog flag `toplevel_print_options` which is initially:

```
?- current_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, Options).
   Options = [quoted(true),numbervars(true),portrayed(true),max_depth(10)].
```

To remove the depth limit for writing set (e.g. in your `.sicstusrc`).

```
 :- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options,
        [quoted(true),numbervars(true),portrayed(true),max_depth(0)]).
```

(As a beginner, rather avoid to use side-effectful built-ins as much as you can - even if you "only" print terms. This is a distraction you can easily avoid.)